# Electrolux Induction Range: E 75 Error Code

Tags: electrical, repair, stove, range

I have a 10 year old Electrolux induction range. Model: EW30lS6CJSB. I was cooking on Power booster mode (Pb) that suddenly I heard a bang and noticed a red flash light on upper left corner of cooktop and then shut down entirely. I noticed that the circuit breaker for induction range tripped. Once I turned it back on, it is showing E 75. None of heat elements of the cooktops is currently working but the oven is working fine. I asked a technician to come and have a look. Without even opening up the stove he said,  “PCB Main board control” should be replaced which is about $1600.

**Question 1**: Do you agree with this diagnose? Would there be any chance that e.g. filter board is gone and should be replaced?

**Question 2**: Is it worth paying for a repair?

Thanks

Comment: Repair or replace questions will depend on price of a new unit and age.  10 plus years any repair over 30% of new would be questionable, my opinion.  Hearing bangs from any cooking device usually not good.

Comment: New one would cost 5-6 K$

Comment: Since you heard a loud bang, I am afraid the damage is severe.

Answer (score 1):

If the power supply is good and no wire popped loose due to overcurrent all fingers point to the generator around $1000.

Thanks to modern low voltage control modules which are susceptible to power surges.

Typical things that give out:   Relays, transistors, capacitors, including smd types, resistors, and regulators. And sometimes the transformer which mitigates the high frequency DC.